# Retrieve data from SQL Server 2005 in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, asp.net-4.0

I'm writing a class to abstract away the stored procedures, but am stuck on the basics of opening a connection to the database.

Examples I've seen use the SqlConnection class, which is what I intend to do, however, I don't seem to find it in the System.Data namespace.

I think this might be a configuration/setup issue. I'm using Visual Web Developer to write this.

Is there a way to fix this, or should I switch to a "proper" version of Visual Studio?

Comment: To clarify, System.Data is found, but System.Data.SqlClient is not.

Comment: Check your project has a reference to the System.Data assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) for [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx)

Try:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

// Use SqlConnection now
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that would make that happen is if you do not have the appropriate references to the assembly concerned. Please check to make sure that the assembly reference to System.Data has been added to your solution and also you have imported the system.Data.SqlClient namespace in to your class file.
This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

VWD is just fine for what you are doing.  Ensure that your connection string is correct, and as kd7 said you need the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

Visual Web Developer, Visual C#/VB, Visual Studio (full versions), they can all utilize this namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace instead `System.Data`

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that you have the System.Data reference in your project.